# If cell value > .01, cell font color = red

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any way to change a cell's font color based on its value within the cell and not use a macro?

Comment: you mean like conditional formatting?

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Doc's Spreadsheets allow this - perhaps where you got the idea? -- Just commenting for those who haven't seen that anywhere before.

Comment: Removed the vba tag, since you specifically do NOT want a macro.

Comment: Pretty much every spreadsheet app that I am aware of does conditional formatting...google docs, open office, excel...

Answer (score 6):

Highlight your Column and then select Conditional Formatting from the Home Menu. Select Highlight COL Rules and then Greater than...

[image]

Enter your conditions and select your color.

[image]

Comment: fyi oops. I did greater than .1 but you meant .01.